# On change screen orientation, new activity created

Tags: java, android, android-activity, youtube, screen-orientation

I'm relatively new to Android but have made quite a few apps over the past year so forgive me.

I know that when you are running an app on a device and change the screen orientation by turning the device the activity that is showing is completely recreated. I go to the youtube app (I am using Nexus 7 w/ Android 4.2.2) and play some video and then flip the screen to change orientation. The video keeps playing and everything is re-sized accordingly... How is this possible if the activity is completely recreated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml add, android:configChanges and this would avoid the activity being re-created on orientation change. I hope your landscape and portrait mode has the same layout.

```
    <activity android:label="Your Activity Name" 
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      android:name="com.yourpackage">
```

To add more to this, i would suggest you to look at the `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods and if you are playing with Fragments then have a watch on `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRetainInstanceState` rather than applying the xml changes as "**Activity is destroyed by design.**"

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: This is bad advice... apps must save their state, that way they can handle rotation changes as well as the OS reaping their memory (when the user leaves for a while). Using this method is really designed for complicated apps that are too expensive to restart on rotate, which most apps are not.

Comment: @StevenByle: I agree with you, i have indicated clearly over the activity life cycle to look upon in my post, coz Activity is destroyed by design.

Comment: This method is used by a huge percentage of all apps on the market.  The whole destroying the activity and restarting it on rotation was a huge mistake by google-  it's confusing, causes bugs, and is a large source of programmer pain.  The fact that they had to implement not one but two hacks to get around it is proof that its just a bad idea.  Unless your app needs that functionality because it has totally separate landscape and portrait mode layouts this is the correct way to fix it-  completely avoid Google's bad ideas, and they'll eventually realize they screwed up and change it.

Comment: He should have layouts for portrait and landscape. Suppose video has a length of 10 minutes. Plays for 5 minutes changes orientation. Save that state by overriding  onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) and restore the same in  onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: @Raghunandan: thats the way you have to go, but i don't really understand on how come he would have different layouts for both landscape and portrait mode.

Comment: @GabeSechan *sigh*... if you correctly save your state (which you have to in order to recover from the OS destroying your `Activity` in low memory situations or the app is not returned to for some time), you will already cover the restart on rotate, no need to add this cheat into your manifest. Advocating against Google's recommendations (WHO WROTE THE OS LOL) is downright foolish. Be glad Google doesn't reject apps like Apple, yours probably wouldn't be in the Play Store ;).

Comment: @Vinothbabu layout-port : layout for portrait orientation

layout-land : layout for landscape orientation. Provide proper height and width of the layouts

Comment: @Raghunandan: i get it raghu, but how do you say that that the video content would have both potrait and landscape layouts... i would say its a guess as either the OP has not posted out anything over this.

Comment: @StevenByle If my app is killed due to low memory, I'd rather have it restart from scratch.  Trying to restart it from a saved state is fragile, buggy, and almost never the right thing to do.  Just because Google wrote the OS doesn't mean they got everything right.  This was a major mistake.  Just avoiding the whole damn problem is right-  which is why most of Google's own apps use it.

Comment: @StevenByle: google either can't, i was reading this article today http://bitboxer.de/2012/09/01/in-wich-i-rant-about-developing-on-android/ litterally speaking its true... some things are real pain to achieve in android.

Comment: @Vinothbabu try playing a youtube video in your device by changing device orientation. You will know.

Comment: @GabeSechan that's what you aren't getting, the whole app will get killed if you leave long enough (and restart), but say you get a phone call while doing something, just a single `Activity`'s memory may have been taken during that call to give to the phone app. Now when you return, the user expects to be where they were, restarting the whole app would happen all the time, and be annoying. With save/restore, Android lets devices work like they have much more RAM than they actually do, it's quite innovative. Also, I save/restore state in a 50k+ line app with 500k+ users... works fine...

Comment: Its not innovative, its a broken idea.  Its not how programs work, its not how OSes work, it requires a great deal of tedious work by the developer and is very likely to break because the developer misses something-  and its not even what the user expects (really, ask a non-technical user if they expect an app to be in the same state after leaving it for a few hours.  None of them do, they think when they hit back it exits). Nor do I want it to persist-  its a horrible idea for security reasons.  So they implement a bad idea to make another bad idea possible.  No thanks.

Comment: Laughing out loud reading this... 1. When you hit back, it does exit (doesn't save state). 2. After a few hours, the app will almost always have been killed and restart. Saving state is a smaller time frame than that. 3. The saved states do not persist, and rely on the security features of separate processes in Linux, which is very secure. It's clear you have no idea why the OS even restarts Actvities on config changes, it's to allow apps to provide config specific resources. If it didn't restart them, you would have to handle every config specific resource in code (your dumb idea).

Answer (score -1):

If you are worried about losing the value of local variables within your activity... You could use Singleton Pattern for some of those variables. This not a beautiful solution, but could work.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.